# Alternative to Dynamic Sitemaps in Rails 4.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sitemap

I have been using [dynamic_sitemaps](https://github.com/lassebunk/dynamic_sitemaps) for my Rails application for sometime, but it doesn't seem to be supported anymore. It stopped working after I upgraded from Rails 4.1.6 to 4.2.3. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've moved over to the [sitemap_generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator) gem, which also, by the way, is framework agnostic.

Just in case someone else stumbles upon this question.